# How to convert a column into an index with the same existing values as indices?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `DataFrame` called `products` and it has this structure and data:

[image: Products]

I want to know how do I convert the `Product ID` index into a column with the same values and become the index for the `DataFrame`.

I've tried

```
products = products.reset_index()
```

and this is what I got:

[image: new products DataFrame]

What I want to get is:

[image: New DataFrame with the required index]

Comment: You can't have a `DataFrame` without an index... so when you use `.reset_index()` making the index a column - it's putting in a default index. What difficulties is this causing you? eg: what's wrong with Product ID as the index/or as a column but with a default index?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for obtaining the desired result:

```
products = products.set_index('Product ID')
```

[image]

Comment: It works perfectly for me. I have attached a screenshot for reference.